# Question regarding the implementation of the paper " guided random walks" weighing functions

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, scikit-image, random-walk

- I'm working on the implementation of the paper: [Segmentation by retrieval with guided random walks: Application to left ventricle segmentation in MRI](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.media.2012.10.005).
- I tried to modify the weights functions mentioned in Scikit-Image [random walker algorithm](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/segmentation/random_walker_segmentation.py) to fulfil the mathematical model explained in the paper, as in the photo down.
- My questions is :

  1. Is this implementation of the **weight functions** according to the paper is correct?
  2. Why the original function on [random walker algorithm](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/segmentation/random_walker_segmentation.py) reverse the signal of the weights to negative at end?
     [image: Mathematical Model]

```
def compute_weights_3d(data,raw,alpha, beta, eps=1.e-6):
    # raw is the test image(3D grayscale), data is an image from prior knowledge(3D grayscale)
    # raw and data have same size, while data has a driver(label) 
    # Weight calculation is main difference in multispectral version
    # Original gradient**2 replaced with sum of gradients ** 2
    inter_gradients = np.concatenate([np.diff(data[..., 0], axis=ax).ravel()
         for ax in [2, 1, 0] if data.shape[ax] > 1], axis=0) ** 2 # gradient ^2
    intra_gradients = (raw - data)**2
    # Normalize gradients
    inter_gradients = (inter_gradients - np.amin(inter_gradients))/(np.amax(inter_gradients)- np.amin(inter_gradients))
    intra_gradients = (intra_gradients - np.amin(intra_gradients))/(np.amax(intra_gradients)- np.amin(intra_gradients))

    # All dimensions considered together in this standard deviation
    #------------------------------------------------------
    inter_scale_factor  = -beta  / (10 * data.std())
    inter_weights = np.exp(inter_scale_factor * inter_gradients)
    inter_weights += eps
    #------------------------------------------------------
    intra_scale_factor  = -alpha / (10 * data.std())
    inter_weights = np.exp(intra_scale_factor * intra_gradients)
    intra_weights += eps
    #------------------------------------------------------
    return -inter_weights, -intra_weights
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Answer is that:

1. The implementation of the weight functions according to the paper is incorrect,
   Down the correct one.
2. They reversed the signal on weighing function and reversed it back again in the matrices calculation so there is no difference.

```
def compute_weights(image,mask,alpha, beta, eps=1.e-6):
    # Weight calculation is main difference in multispectral version
    # Original gradient**2 replaced with sum of gradients ** 2
    intra_gradients = np.concatenate([np.diff(image, axis=ax).ravel()
     for ax in [1, 0] ], axis=0) ** 2            # gradient ^2
    # print('intra_gradients shape',intra_gradients.shape)
    # 5-Connected
    inter_gradients = np.concatenate([np.diff(mask, axis=ax).ravel()
    for ax in [1, 0] ], axis=0)**2 
    # inter_gradients = np.concatenate((inter_gradients,(mask-image).ravel()),axis=0)**2  # gradient ^2
    # print('inter_gradients shape',inter_gradients.shape)
    #----------------------------------------
    # 1-Connected
    # inter_gradients = (image - mask)**2
    #----------------------------------------
    # Normalize gradients
    intra_gradients = (intra_gradients - np.amin(intra_gradients))/(np.amax(intra_gradients)- np.amin(intra_gradients))
    inter_gradients = (inter_gradients - np.amin(inter_gradients))/(np.amax(inter_gradients)- np.amin(inter_gradients))
    # print('Intra Gradiesnt_Shape: ',intra_gradients.shape)    
    # All dimensions considered together in this standard deviation
    #------------------------------------------------------
    intra_scale_factor  = -beta  / (10 * image.std())
    intra_weights = np.exp(intra_scale_factor * intra_gradients)
    intra_weights += eps
    #------------------------------------------------------
    inter_scale_factor  = -alpha / (10 * image.std())
    inter_weights = np.exp(inter_scale_factor * inter_gradients)
    inter_weights += eps
    #------------------------------------------------------
    return -intra_weights, inter_weights # [W_old , w_new]
```